# How to add a field with a reserved keyword as its name to a structure?

Tags: vlang

I'm trying to add a field called `type` to a V structure used for the C interop. It is failing, because `type` is a keyword too.

The original structure in C:

```c
typedef struct some_s {
  int type;
} some_t;
```

The structure declared in V:

```golang
#include "some.h"

[typedef]
struct C.some_t {
  type int
}
```

The error when trying to compile the V source:

```
❯ v some.v
some.v:17:2: error: unexpected keyword `type`, expecting name
   15 | [typedef]
   16 | struct C.some_t {
   17 |   type int
      |   ~~~~
   18 | }
```

Is there a way to mark the `type` as a name of a structure field?

Comment: You'll likely have to rename the field in V. Fortunately, field names are not critical to the struct.

Comment: Is it possible, @Ouroborus? If I declare the struct with `etype`: `[typedef] struct C.some_t { etype int }`, the compilation will continue, but it'll fail later, when the C structure will be used. For example, this code: `if s.etype == 0 { break }` will fail with this error: `error: field designator 'etype' does not refer to any field in type 'some_t' (aka 'struct some_s'); did you mean 'type'?`. I'd need V to "translate" an access to a renamed field to the original name `type`, when interoperating with C. I couldn't find a flag to rename the field like it's possible in JSON serialisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got help from Petr in the chat at [Discord for V](https://discord.com/channels/592103645835821068/592294828432424960/1109794424055140454). Thanks a lot!

It's simple - if you need to use an identifier, which matches an existing keyword, just prefix it with `@`.

The structure declared in V, now properly:

```golang
#include "some.h"

[typedef]
struct C.some_t {
  @type int
}
```

The note about the `@` prefix is "well hidden" :-) in the [documentation of enums](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/master/doc/docs.md#enums):

> Enum fields cannot re-use reserved keywords. However, reserved keywords may be escaped with an @.